# Straight forward modelform doesn't validate on submit of form

Tags: django

I have a fairly simple ModelForm which doesn't validate on submit.
If I loop the form's fields it renders two select fields `name` and `company` and it only validates If I provide both selections:

```
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
```

If I try both `{{ form.company }}` or `{{ form.name }}` it renders the correct choices for the select but it doesn't validate in both cases.

So why it only validates if I render two selects

```
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
```

or

```
    {{  form.name }}
    {{  form.company }}
```

and selecting a choice for each of the selects?

[image]

```
# views.py

def render_entities(request):
    """View to render the entities overview page"""

    # Get the logged in user instance
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    user_cashpool = Cashpool.objects.get(company__user=user)

    # Get the info for the site visited
    dashboard_site = 'entities'

    if request.method == 'GET':

        # Return the form and populate with user's company
        company = user.company

        # Query all entities associated to the cashpool
        companies = Company.objects.filter(cashpool=user_cashpool).order_by('name')

        # Pass the queryset to the Select Form
        CompanyForm.base_fields['company'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=companies)

        # Return the form
        form = CompanyForm()

        context = {
            'company': company,
            'companies': companies,
            'dashboard_site': dashboard_site,
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard_entities.html', context)

    else:
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():    # fails

            # Get the cleaned inputs
            company = form.cleaned_data['company']
    ...
```

```
# forms.py

class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form to render a select widget with companies associated to a user
    """
    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.exclude(name='exclude-all'), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['name']
```

```
# template

    <!-- Select Company -->
    <form action="entities" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <label for="company">Select a Company</label>
        {{ form.name }}
        <button type="submit" value="Load Company" class="submit-button">Load Company</button>
    </form>
```

```
# models.py

class Company(models.Model):


    # Meta
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: what does `print(form.errors)` return if you put it after `form.is_valid`?

Comment: @Stoobish added to the post, thanks

Comment: I think you need to set `name` in your form, since its part of your CompanyForm. The form can't find name so it's failing the validation, as said in the `form.errors` output.

Comment: @Stoobish you mean in the forms.py? I tried this but didnt help

Comment: I'm wondering if `form = CompanyForm()` is enough to instanciate your form, shouldn't you write `form = CompanyForm(instance=company)` instead to populate form fields?

Comment: @Christophe but I want to pass the queryset `companies` to the form. Not sure if this would work

Comment: If I'm not wrong, if you need to pass more than one raw, you do not need a form, but a formset. I'm new to this part (and that's another reason I'm interested in your topic), but as far as I understand your code, you send an empty form to the front at this stage

Comment: @Christophe the form right now renders the correct company names, I add a screenshot to the post

Comment: OK, looks fine, but sorry this will not help you ;-)

Comment: Can you check what your form returns in the views.py (before the is_valid)? I still think you need to tie the actual company field to name as it’s a required field in Company model.

Comment: @Stoobish posted it :)

Comment: Try a simple  {{form.as_p}} (i.e. all Django defaults). Does it then work? If so compare Django's HTML with your template to find out what detail you are missing.

Comment: @nigel222 that worked! But I dont get it why {{ form.name }} doesnt work

Comment: Now "View page source" and print, for the working one and your template. Compare the fine details of the Django-generated input and select elements, with yours. Something will be missing from your template.

Comment: Your name from the `Company` model is probably the one missing.